# Strategies for uploading big files in REST service

Tags: java, rest

Below is simple code from my application and it uploads files, Java web app.

```
@POST
    @Path("/uploadDocument")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadDocument(
           @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
           @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader) {
```

As you see it is jersey code (I also have CXF services on other application with the same issue) and it is one POST for file.

What would happen if file is too big and when it is too big for such service? Every server has some timeout settings so it would throw RequestTimeoutException. Does HTTP protocol (when REST service is used) do some chunking behind? Does this annotation means chunking in case of REST service?

```
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
```

would be enough for this?

Or maybe REST provides something like MTOM in webSerives?

Comment: big file will result in service timeout. It need to be handled differently. (it does not chunk by default) There are many ways to do this. for example partition files.

Comment: I cant find any examples / tutorials for "rest partition files", what do u mean?

Comment: Guys, where are some ideas ;)

Comment: I also have spring batch in my project, this is not for REST services, but for bulk processing of data in background what do u mean?

Answer (score -1):

In these kind of scenario's i would be limiting the file upload size [example here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)